# How to convert HTML to text keeping linebreaks

Tags: java, html

How may I convert HTML to text keeping linebreaks (produced by elements like br,p,div, ...) possibly using [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) or any decent enough HTML parser

Example:
`Hello<br/>World`
to:

```
Hello\n  
World
```

Comment: go ahead, just do it! Btw, what **is** your question?

Comment: I think the question is one of rendering as Neko appears to be only a parser. For example a <p> element is word-wrapped by an HTML renderer but not by a parser. If this guess is correct, the post is underspecified as to what the output should be rendered as.

Comment: There's another question discussing your problem, and I've found propsed by @Mirco Attocchi pretty amazing and it works great for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6031463/1249304

Answer (score 8):

Here is a function I made to output text (including line breaks) by iterating over the nodes using Jsoup.

```
public static String htmlToText(InputStream html) throws IOException {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(html, null, "");
    Element body = document.body();

    return buildStringFromNode(body).toString();
}

private static StringBuffer buildStringFromNode(Node node) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        TextNode textNode = (TextNode) node;
        buffer.append(textNode.text().trim());
    }

    for (Node childNode : node.childNodes()) {
        buffer.append(buildStringFromNode(childNode));
    }

    if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        String tagName = element.tagName();
        if ("p".equals(tagName) || "br".equals(tagName)) {
            buffer.append("\n");
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: I've added the following to make it include links:

if ("a".equals(tagName)){buffer.append(node.attr("href")); buffer.append("\n"); }

Answer (score 3):

```
w3m -dump -no-cookie input.html > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I did find a relatively clever solution in [html2txt: THE ASCIINATOR](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) which does an admirable job of producing nroff like output (e.g. like `man ls` run on a terminal). It produces output in the [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) style that StackOverflow uses as input.

For moderately complex pages like this page, the output is [somewhat scattered](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513707/html-to-text-keeping-linebreaks) as it tries mightily to turn non-linear layout into something linear. The output from less complicated markup is [pretty readable](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/?url=http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind hard-wrapped/designed-for-monospace output, `lynx -dump` produces good plain text from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

HTML to Text:
I am taking this statement to mean that all HTML formatting, except line-breaks, will be abandoned.

What I have done for such a venture is using regexp to detect any set of tag enclosure.
If the value within the tags are br or br/, a line-break is inserted, otherwise the tag is discarded.

It works only for simple html pages. Tables will obviously be linearised.

I had been thinking of detecting the title value between the title tag enclosure, so that the converter automatically places the title at the top of the page. Needs to put in a little more algorithm. By my time is better spent with ...

I am reading on using Google Data APIs to upload a document to Google Docs and then using the same API to download/export it as text. Or, why text, when I could do pdf. But you have to get a Google account if you don't already have one.

[Google docs data download/export](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs)

[Google docs data api for java](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html)

Comment: I cannot use external services. The application should even run offline.

Answer (score -2):

Does it matter what language you use? You could always use pattern matching. Basically HTML lien break tags (br,p,div, ...) you can replace with "\n" and remove all the other tags. You could always store the tags in an array so you can easily check when you go through the HTML file. Then any other tags and all the other end tags (/p,..) can be replaced with an empty string therefore getting your result.

Comment: That is one thing a HTML parser like NekoHTML does, but it is not enough since you need other things like entity replacement.