# How to get page's line breaks based on visual representation of html entities (or at least, close to it)?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I have a section of a webpage I identified as my area of interest. It may contain multiple html tags in it, but I want to interpret it as a multiline text, or at least as close as possible to how it's rendered by the browser.

Let me give you an example.

```
<div>
<p>Line 1<p>
</div>
<div><p>Line 2<p></div> <div><p>Line 3 <p></div>
<p>Line 4<p></div><br />Line 5
```

In the browser, it is rendered like this:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3

Line 4

Line 5
```

I want to run the original html through some sort of lib and get a text with the following contents (or close):

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Please note, I don't want to recover the original line breaks present in the Html (as [this question points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text/6031463#6031463). I want to interpret the html entities as line breaks similar to the way it is rendered by the browser. Is there any lib that can do it? I've used Jsoup's [TextNode.getWholeText()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#getWholeText%28%29) but it doesn't parse the html tags.

Edit: for linux users out there, I want something similar to the result of:

```
$ lynx -dump file.html > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<div> tags and <p>` tags by default in HTML have padding and margin blocks around them. So it's obvious that is why the browser is rendering it like it is.

Create a CSS file and disable the padding and margin spacing.

Also, why is Java tagged? If you're doing this in a Java Servlet Page check your `System.out.println` statements.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question right, sir. There are two tags in it. This question's main focus is on web scraping with java, not web design.