# How to parse html and keep ALL line breaks?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a document that contains `<br/> , <p> , and <table>` elements

I have been trying to parse this HTML using `Jsoup` and **preserve the lines**.

I tried [many methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773669/table-from-webpage-jsoup-for-html-and-display-in-jtable) from [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075991/how-to-keep-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-parse) but no result

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:............xxx.htm");
        String htmlText = IOUtils.toString(in);

        File file = new File("C:............xxx.txt") ;
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(file) ; 

        String text = Jsoup.parse(htmlText.replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "br2n")).text();
        System.out.println(text.replaceAll("br2n", "\n"));
        pr.println(text.replaceAll("br2n", "\n"));

//        for (String line : htmlText.split("\n")) {
//            String stripped = Jsoup.parse(line).text();
//            
//            System.out.println(stripped);
//            pr.println(stripped);
//              
//        }

        pr.close();
```

---

---

Here is the representative part of my HTML file *(the original file starts with `<html>` ...of course)*

```
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white"
    width='650'>
    <tr>
    <td><font size="4"><br />
    &nbsp;<b>The scientific explantion of the syndrom</b></font>
    <table width='650' border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width='5%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='25%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='25%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='15%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='30%'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="24">
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap" colspan="3"><font size=
    "3"><b>Recent Update</b></font></td>
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a name=
    "9J003346248"></a><font size="3"><b>Issue:</b></font></td>
    <td align="left"><font size="3">9569865248</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><b>Locust:</b></td>
    <td align="left" colspan="3">UYF78UIGK</td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <br/> The explanation above does not necc....... <p> 
    Blah ....
    </p>

    <table border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white"
    width='750'>
    <tr>
    <td><font size="4"><br />
    &nbsp;<b>Syndrom of the main ......</b></font>
    <table width='650' border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width='5%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='25%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='25%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='15%'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width='30%'>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="24">
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap" colspan="3"><font size=
    "3"><b>Data</b></font></td>
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap"><a name=
    "9J003346248"></a><font size="3"><b>Issue:</b></font></td>
    <td align="left"><font size="3">9509809248</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><b>Locust:</b></td>
    <td align="left" colspan="3">U344365GK</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<br/> The explanation above does not necc....... <p> 
Blah ....
</p>
```

I need to make sure that all rows in those table lie one after another the way they do in the original document. But I have multiple tables and other "line breaking elements". How can I do this using Jsoup? Is it possible to parse html and keep line using other api more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right. Try this

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(htmlText.replaceAll("(?i)</tr>", "</tr> br2n ").replaceAll("(?i)<br[^>]*>", "br2n")).replaceAll("(?i)<p>", "<p> br2n ").replaceAll("(?i)</p>", "</p> br2n ").text();
  System.out.println(text.replaceAll("br2n", "\n"));
```