# getText() with jsoup or tika: having li elements with carriage return

Tags: jsoup, apache-tika

Is it possible, while getting the full text of an html page (with tika or jsoup), to have carriage return between each 'li' element?

Today I have all text in a compact way.

Thanks

Comment: Please give an example of the source html, and the expected output so I can help you further :)

Comment: It sounds like you have some code that does nearly what you want, but not exactly.  You're more likely to get useful help if you show us what you've done and what output you'd like to get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is an improved version of [Andrew Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24374771/1992780).

**Java**

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow33947074;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 33947074
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("file.html");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "");
        Element element = document.select("html").first();
        String text = getText(element);
        System.out.println("Result: " + text);
    }

    /**
     * Get the custom text from the given {@link Element}.
     * @param element The {@link Element} from which get the custom text.
     * @return Returns the custom text.
     */
    private static String getText(Element element) {
        String working = "";
        for (Node child : element.childNodes()) {
             if (child instanceof TextNode) {
                 working += ((TextNode) child).text();
             }
             if (child instanceof Element) {
                 Element childElement = (Element)child;
                 if (childElement.tag().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("li")) {
                      working += "\n";
                 }                  
                 working += getText(childElement);
             }
        }
        return working;
    }
}
```

**file.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jsoup</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a>.</p>
<ul>
    <li>First element</li>
    <li><a href="#">Second element</a></li>
    <li>Third element <b>Additional for third element</b></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

```
Result:  Try jsoup   This is jsoup.  
First element 
Second element 
Third element Additional for third element
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I will try it this afternoon. Regards

Comment: Thanks. With Tika, I overload endElement event and append \n when li element is reached.