# cannot preserve newlines in text read from URL

Tags: java, jsoup

I am reading text from URL using Jsoup. Following link has some tips to preserve new lines when converting the body to text
[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text/19602313#19602313)

I use following lines to convert the tags

```
  String prettyPrintedBodyFragment = Jsoup.clean(body, "", Whitelist
            .none().addTags("br", "p",  "h1"), new OutputSettings()
            .prettyPrint(true));
  System.out.println(prettyPrintedBodyFragment);
```

I still get the body/content in single line. Any clues pl?

**EDIT**: Here is the complete source code and I see output in only 1 line

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/");
        Document doc  = conn.get();

         String body = doc.body().text();

        String prettyPrintedBodyFragment = Jsoup.clean(body, "", Whitelist
                .none().addTags("br", "p",  "h1"), new OutputSettings()
                .prettyPrint(true));

        System.out.println(prettyPrintedBodyFragment);



    }
```

Comment: This works for me. What url are you trying to parse?

Comment: Edited the original post  with the source code for reading from finance.yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`String body = doc.body().text();`

To:

`String body = doc.body().html();`

Since you are already dumping the tags, your `Whitelist` has no way to include them while formatting your text.