# Java Jsoup line break issue

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get this code;

```
<p>Text<br />
New Text<br />
Second Text<br />
Third Text</p>
```

With this code;

```
Elements pResult = p.getElementsByTag("p");
System.out.println(pResult.text());
```

I show this > Text New Text Second Text Third Text

But i want

```
<p>Text <br>New text<br>Second Text<br>Third Text</p>
```

Because of `<br>` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text/6031463#6031463)

Comment: I have no experience Using jsoup, but my guess is following: When you use .text(), this should return plain text content inside <p> tag, without </br> tags. I think what you need to do is to use .html() function: pResult.html(), then replace all <br /> inside your string with newline character and print it. (or you could just split string on <br /> and print afterwards)

Comment: As suggested by @blindProgrammer following provide the output you want `System.out.println(pResult.html().replaceAll("<br>", "\n"))`.

Comment: Edit: as Documentation states, to obtain "<p>Text <br>New text<br>Second Text<br> Third Text</p>"  <--this, you use following: pResult.outerHtml()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
String s="<p>Text<br />\nNew Text<br />\nSecond Text<br />\nThird Text</p>";

System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(s).select("p").outerHtml());
```

#### OUTPUT

```
<p>Text<br> New Text<br> Second Text<br> Third Text</p>
```

**Jsoup 1.8.3**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String s="<p>Text<br /> New Text<br />Second Text<br />Third Text</p>";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(s);
        document.outputSettings(new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false));
        document.select("br").append("\\n");
        document.select("p").prepend("\\n\\n");
        String s1 = document.html().replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
        System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(s1, "", Whitelist.none(), new Document.OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false)));
    }
}
```