# JSoup Element wholeText removing spacing

Tags: jsoup

I am using the following code to parse HTML with JSoup:

```
Jsoup.parse(html).wholeText()
```

My html samples will include text like the following:

```
<p>some text</p><br /><br>later
```

However, the output from JSoup is always:

```
some textlater
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
some text

later
```

(note the line returns after 'some text' and 'later')

Is there a different method instead of wholeText that I should use if I want to retain spacing? I did find the following stackoverflow question which was similar:
[How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text)

However, the problem with that question is that all of the users wanted to use string replacements or regex to look for br or other specific tags. I am looking for something more general purpose (like an html parser that removes html tags while retaining line breaks and other whitespace - it doesn't have to be jsoup either if there is a better java library).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);`

which will convert your string into html nodes for manipulation
then use

`doc.outputSettings().indentAmount(0).prettyPrint(false);`

to keep the space and styling in place.

then to return the html to string

`doc.body().html().toString();`