# Jsoup replace <br> and <span> tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I parsed information from website:

```
document.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "description")
        .last()
        .parent()
        .select("span")
        .first();
```

And get following String:

```
<span jsslot>Bug fixes and improvements.<br>Added support for bluetooth controllers from iPega, 8BitDo and more.<br>Fixed missing assets issue on Nvidia Shield.</span>
```

Now I want to remove span tags and replace br tag with new line ("\n"). Tried something like this:

```
document.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "description")
        .last()
        .parent().select("span")
        .first().select("span")
        .prepend("")
        .select("br").append("\n").text()
```

But get empty string.

Comment: See [How do I preserve line breaks when using jsoup to convert html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640334/how-do-i-preserve-line-breaks-when-using-jsoup-to-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: Tried all, nothing works.